# not displaying result in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i tried to use print_r($list) but the result array().There is no element in the array.I want to show data form my table.there is user table, job table and industry table.Can anybody suggest me where is mistake.

This is my model function get_data_by_query used in controller

```
public function get_data_by_query($qry)
        {
            $query = $this->db->query($qry);    
            return $query->result();
        }
```

This is my controller where i am verifying email, phone number.

```
public function Dashboard()
{
    if ($this->Common_model->Is_User_Logged()) 
    {   
        $condition='';

        $data['email_verified']=self::IsEmailVerified();
        $data['phone_verified']=self::IsPhoneVerified();
        $userdata=$this->session->userdata('user_logged_in');

        $data['user_email']=$userdata['email']; 
        //print_r($data);

        $res=$this->Common_model->get_data_by_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id={$userdata['id']} limit 1");
                //print_r($res);
        $data['user_skills'] = $res[0]->user_skills;
                    //print_r($data);
               $arr = array($res[0]->user_skills);
               //print_r($arr[0]);
               //exit;
                    $condition.=" and FIND_IN_SET(job_title,'$arr[0]')";
        print_r($condition);
        $sql_get="SELECT j.*,j.job_industry,i.industry_title
        FROM job j
        LEFT JOIN industry i on i.industry_id=j.job_industry
        WHERE job_status=1 ".$condition." ";
        //print_r($sql_get);

        $data['list']=$this->Common_model->get_data_by_query($sql_get);
        //print_r($data['list']);

        $data['user_phone']=$res[0]->user_mobile;
        $this->load->view('user/header');
        $this->load->view('user/home', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/footer');
    }
    else 
    {
        redirect('user');
    }
}
```

This is my view

```
            <?php 
                if(!empty($list)>0)
                    { 
                    foreach ($list as $row) 
                        {
            ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row->job_role;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row->industry_title;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row->job_vacancy;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row->job_keyword;?></td>
              <!--<td><?php echo $row->job_type;?></td>-->
            </tr>
            <?php
              } }
            ?>
```

what is the reason that $list is empty array although i have data in my table. I will be thankful for you.

Comment: How do you use `$res` ? You get data, put it in `$res`, and only send `$data` to your view.

Comment: still not giving result.can you look once  again the code please

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of effort, i found that there is no problem in above code. The problem is in tje SQL query. I am trying to resolve that query.